# Break end of cloth mesh into particles in an infinite looping animation

Tags: animation, particles, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to experiment with both Cloth physics and particles, and I need a little help.

I have a character with a long coat, and I'm trying to get the bottom edge of his coat to kind of... break(?) into little bits, like embers or smoke or something; but at the same time, I don't want to break his entire coat.

Cloth physics work OK on the coat itself - it behaves.

Is this possible? Just to 'break' a little bit of his coat while still allowing it to move like clothing?

Tell me if I'm being too vague, and sorry in advance if I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a particle system after the cloth one and then use [Explode modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Simulate/Explode) to break the mesh.

[image]

If you input a vertex weight map to protect some faces it will randomly break the unprotected ones and create effect like this:

[image]

Comment: great idea! But how would I go about looping it? (noob question, I know, but I'm curious)

Comment: how the loop looks like, the cloth needs to assembled back? like a ping pong animation? you can do this in postprocessing